# Running "ansible-playbook playbook.yml" outputs fatal: [localhost]: FAILED

Tags: ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

Following the ansible 2-org-network example tutorial, when running "ansible-playbook playbook.yml" command, this outputs 
**"TASK [ibm.blockchain_platform_manager : Authenticate to IBM Blockchain Platform service] *****************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"context\":{\"requestId\":\"3aed45737c8d4cc7a3a52b03cfbf7e64\",\"requestType\":\"incoming.Identity_Token\",\"userAgent\":\"ansible-httpget\",\"url\":\"https://iam.cloud.ibm.com\",\"instanceId\":\"iamid-5.2-7439-f51ff7a-6488f4d469-jxdn5\",\"threadId\":\"f61a\",\"host\":\"iamid-5.2-7439-f51ff7a-6488f4d469-jxdn5\",\"startTime\":\"15.02.2020 21:04:28:625 GMT\",\"endTime\":\"01.01.1970 00:00:00:000 GMT\",\"elapsedTime\":\"0\",\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"clusterName\":\"iam-id-prams03-igyr\"},\"errorCode\":\"BXNIM0415E\",\"errorMessage\":\"Provided API key could not be found\"}", "content_language": "en-US", "content_length": "517", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Sat, 15 Feb 2020 21:04:28 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "json": {"context": {"clusterName": "iam-id-prams03-igyr", "elapsedTime": "0", "endTime": "01.01.1970 00:00:00:000 GMT", "host": "iamid-5.2-7439-f51ff7a-6488f4d469-jxdn5", "instanceId": "iamid-5.2-7439-f51ff7a-6488f4d469-jxdn5", "locale": "en_US", "requestId": "3aed45737c8d4cc7a3a52b03cfbf7e64", "requestType": "incoming.Identity_Token", "startTime": "15.02.2020 21:04:28:625 GMT", "threadId": "f61a", "url": "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com", "userAgent": "ansible-httpget"}, "errorCode": "BXNIM0415E", "errorMessage": "Provided API key could not be found"}, "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", "redirected": false, "set_cookie": "sessioncookie=76599c5849373452d151007c6314be2a; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly", "status": 400, "transaction_id": "3aed45737c8d4cc7a3a52b03cfbf7e64", "url": "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token", "x_powered_by": "Servlet/3.1"}
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

"**
I don't know if this an error, but a node file should be created but it's not. a screenshot of the output is attached [image]

Edit: I'm using ibm blockchain platform vscode extension. changed the infrastructure.type from "saas" to "software" while the previous error is gone another one apperead "I'm using the ibm platform extension on vs code. changed the infrastructre.type from "saas" to "software" in the "playbook.yaml" file, that error is gone but a new appeared 
**"fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: ", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://ibp-console.example.org:32000/ak/api/v1/components?skip_cache=yes"}
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=11   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

"** [image]

Answer (score 0):

The ansible role provides support for 3 options, `saas`, `software` and `docker`.

`saas` refers to IBM Blockchain platform in the cloud, ie the software as a service offering in IBM Cloud, so you need to have provisioned IBM Blockchain platform on the IBM Cloud for this option.

`software` refers to IBM Blockchain platform software which you need to purchase from IBM and have it deployed.

`docker` refers to a local deployment on your machine using docker of the Open Source Hyperledger images it creates a local fabric network on your machine.

I'm guessing that you would want to use the `docker` option.

Comment: changed it but now it gives me another error "TASK [ibm.blockchain_platform_manager : Enroll the user] ***********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "fabric-ca-client enroll -u 'https://admin:********@localhost:18050' --caname ca -M /home/arwa/Desktop/ansible-examples/two-org-network/wallets/Org1/admin --tls.certfiles /home/arwa/Desktop/ansible-examples/two-org-network/wallets/Org1/ca-tls-root.pem", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}"

Comment: try raising an issue about the example at https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ansible-examples or at the https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ansible-role-blockchain-platform-manager itself